# get author of published post

Tags: plugin-development, users, author

I am using the publish_post action to run some checks on a user after their post is published:

```
$author_ID = ????

add_action('publish_post', 'rhb_check_current_user', 10, $author_ID);
```

How can I get the original author's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`add_action('publish_post', 'rhb_check_current_user');`

and in your rhb_check_current_user function check using the global $post:

```
function rhb_check_current_user(){
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This would work if everybody published their own articles, however I want to get the original author's ID (not the person who reviewed the article).

Comment: Isn't it easier if the reviewer doesn't change the original Author of that article? If not mistaken, once you change the original Author even post revision doesn't store that info.